# What's the usage of storing recorded measurements of multimeter and soldering iron station in computer?

Tags: measurement, multimeter, soldering-iron-station

Assume you want to purchase a multimeter for your job. some multimeters have a USB interface to store the recorded measurements in the computer and for this feature, you have to pay more money. but the question is What's the usage of storing recorded measurements in computer? sometimes I think that's a worthless feature, maybe bucause I never need to such feature. but I guss there is a reason for this feature. another device that I think have this feature and that's a worthless feature for it again is soldering iron station. for example: [Weller WX soldering iron station](http://www.apexhandtools.com/weller/np_industrial.cfm) indeed I'm curious!

Comment: In so far as the soldering iron goes, that website claims that it can be used for firmare update, adjustments to parameters and data logging. As far as data logging goes, i can't think of a better way to diagnose impending iron failure than real time temperature and power readings. And on a high end station it definitely makes sense to have an interface in which you could adjust the PID constants to suit a particular task. Personally I think the need to update firmware on a soldering iron a bit - odd, maybe, but understandable given the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multimeter with USB readout can be useful when a large number repetitive measurements has to be made.  Computer readout helps save time and reduces a probability of a data entry error.

- Create test documentation (semi)automatically for each unit under test (UUT, DUT) during quality control (QC).
- Observe trends during QC, which may point to upcoming issues.
- Collect data during routine maintenance.
- Collect data during field research.

*p.s.* There are even [calipers with computer readout](http://43oh.com/2010/12/interfacing-ti-launchpad-to-digital-caliper/).  I have used them for measuring lesions after RF tissue ablation.  Our study required several hundred measurements.

Comment: and for soldering iron?

Comment: @Roh  Central monitoring of the soldering iron temperature settings for the purposes of correcting a technician, who sets an inappropriate temperature.  That's the only guess that comes to mind.  Honestly though, I don't know about soldering iron with USB readout.